# AG9205S PoE PD Module and Raspberry PI

Tags: poe

I have in my hand a [AG9205s](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/1048/Ag9200-datasheet-High-efficiency-Power-over-Ethern-1804404.pdf) PoE PD module (output 5V and up to 13W) and I want to use it with my Raspberry PI 3B+ (that exposes the center core tap wires to the J14 pin header, as you can check here in the [schematic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_3bplus_1p0_reduced.pdf))

Now comes my question: the [AG9205s](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/1048/Ag9200-datasheet-High-efficiency-Power-over-Ethern-1804404.pdf) module shows that the external bridge rectifiers are needed as external part of the PoE PD module, as you can see here:

[image]

But at page 4 of the [Datasheet](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/1048/Ag9200-datasheet-High-efficiency-Power-over-Ethern-1804404.pdf), it says that the output of bridge rectifiers are connected to the respective internal pins, as shown below:

[image]

I'm a little bit confused...I've tried to connect the [AG9205s](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/1048/Ag9200-datasheet-High-efficiency-Power-over-Ethern-1804404.pdf) module to the Raspberry Pi and works without any issue!

What am I missing? Are those bridge rectifiers inside the [AG9205s](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/1048/Ag9200-datasheet-High-efficiency-Power-over-Ethern-1804404.pdf) module? Are they inside the LAN connector of the Raspberry?
Do I need to add those rectifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What am I missing? Are those bridge rectifiers inside the AG9205s
> module?*

No, they are **not** inside - they are required in case the supply polarity coming down the ethernet line reverses or is reversed. You basically just got lucky when you tested it and happened to connect positive to the correct pin (1 or 3).

Comment: Thanks Andy, maybe i can use a pair of those DB207S (https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1810171510_MDD-Microdiode-Electronics-DB207S_C29174.pdf) as input bridge rectifier? they can be suitable?

Comment: I'd use a bridge compatible [with this technical note](https://www.bourns.com/docs/technical-documents/technical-library/chip-diodes/application-notes/bourns-how-to-apply-ac-rectifiers-appnote.pdf?sfvrsn=e35d47f6_12). Note that schottky diodes are recommended @VirtApp. Also note that if there's data on those lines you need low capacitance diodes to prevent any likelihood of data corruptions.