# Raspberry Pi 4B POE Rectifier Circuit recommendation

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, transformer, raspberry-pi, poe

***Am I doing the signal rectification properly for the POE application using the Diodes on the RPI 4B 4 pin header?***

I have attached images of my design, as I am trying to use a Raspberry PI 4B with POE (Power Over Ethernet). I have essentially built a custom hat while taking advantage of the internal Raspberry PI POE twisted pair transformer output 4 pin header. I used a diode array as a rectifier. This is my first time implementing anything of this nature, and I am fairly new to PCB design.

Is this the best route to isolating the signals and providing proper polarity to my transformer? I have tried really hard to understand the nature of the pi as well, and it seems a constant 57V is supplied on one of the four pins, while one other provides the respective Earth Ground.

I found [other examples](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/552505/ag9205s-poe-pd-module-and-raspberry-pi) showing the need for a rectifier on the output 4 pin provided by the PI. Here is the established understanding of the [provided 4 pin header](https://di-marco.net/docs/n0d3-b0x_v2/pi_poe/).

I really would like peace of mind that this design that I have created will work for all Pi 4Bs, as I have actually already failed designing one POE device due to an issue with grounding and not following proper keep out areas for isolation (I think).

The 57V measured signal is isolated and supplied to the [Ferrite Beads](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/447/KEM_FB0002_Z_PWZ-3316852.pdf), passing through the [Inductor (XAL5050-103MEC)](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/597/xal50xx-270657.pdf), then to our [5V-out 25W FCT1-50M22SL POE Forward Transformer](https://www.coilcraft.com/getmedia/fe569a42-533f-4322-ab3b-764883f54979/fct1xxm22sl.pdf). Further, the PGND signal is isolated from my signal ground post transformer through three 1n/2000V 2000V X7R Capacitor connections. The POE IC is the [MP8009GV](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/277/MP8009GV_Z-2946113.pdf)

[image][image]

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: Edited, thanks please take a look

Comment: I think it worth disscussing about how you fail earlier as I presumed that it is your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the best route to isolating the signals and providing proper
> polarity to my transformer?

Yes, the design looks good.

The design looks fine, you have the rectifier diodes in the right location, and each POE pair can have the voltage reversed and it will still reach your DC/DC converter. The snubbers also look correct.

I am not sure how your ground is for the 'chassis ground' but this can also be tied back to the data pairs, this may not be possible on an RPI due to the headers. It's not necessary, just makes things a little nicer.
[image]
Source: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua469/slua469.pdf?ts=1708510994552&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

You also say you have isolation, this is useful if you need to be absolutely 802.3af or at compliant but not necessary if you just want to power a device.